# Unable to upload application manifestation file

Tags: c#, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create an application which authenticate with  azure ad. I have created a web api using visual studio and a native client application with azure portal . Then when I tried to add a webapi under “permission to other application”  I am unable to find the webapi , but it is there. I have changed the manifestation file and added the below entry to it

I am refering to this http://www.codemag.com/article/1503041

```
  "oauth2Permissions": [
    {
      "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application full access to your API on behalf of the signed-in user",
      "adminConsentDisplayName": "Have full access",
      "id": "A1AED6C3-1897-4919-B06E-CDB5B6AF1BD5",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "origin": "Application",
      "type": "User",
      "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application full access to the service on your behalf",
      "userConsentDisplayName": "Have full access to the service",
      "value": "user_impersonation"
    }
  ]
```

I am unable to upload the manifestation  files because of an error as shown below.

> ParameterValidationException=Invalid parameters provided;
>   BadRequestException=Property value cannot be deleted unless it is
>   disabled first.;

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the above i have added a new GUID which is not allowed, so i changed it back and after adding the key's in the configuration section of the web api it worked.